# No compiler found in your classpath! (you may need to add 'tools.jar') Axis 1.4 + Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, axis

I already did everything to correct this error, since the modified environment variables , already put the tools.jar within the tomcat9.0 / bin and / lib in addition to the axis / WEB -INF / lib.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


-<soapenv:Body>


-<soapenv:Fault>

<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>

<faultstring>java.lang.RuntimeException: No compiler found in your classpath! (you may need to add 'tools.jar')</faultstring>


-<detail>

<ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">DESKTOP-MRKMOSG</ns1:hostname>

</detail>

</soapenv:Fault>

</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

AMBIENTE:

CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77

PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin

CLASSPATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Comment: "I need urgent help !" perhaps tops the list of things to say to ensure you will not receive _urgent help_.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

I know that is an old question but I just figure out a way to solve a same problem.

In the *axis\lib* folder there is no *tools.jar* file. **That file is on your *JDK\lib* folder. So just copy that jar file and paste it on the *axis\lib* folder.**

*P.S.* Make sure that you have already defined a system variable called **AXISCLASSPATH** with value the destination of the jar files (e.g. *C:\Program Files\axis-1_4\lib*).

Comment: This answer helped me. I created a system variable named AXISCLASSPATH="[axis_path]/lib:[jdk_path]/lib" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ToolProvider class (which is what is used to get your hands on the Java compiler inside Java program) assumes the tools.jar is either on the boot classpath or in $JAVA_HOME/lib or $JAVA_HOME/../lib in case Java home is pointing to a JRE instead of the full JDK.